# Passing functions in ReactJS as props for components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am a beginner to using ReactJS and I created a component like this:

```
function InputField(props){
    return <div>
        <label htmlFor={props.Id}>{props.label}</label>
        <input type={props.type} id={props.Id} value={props.value} 
        onChange={props.changeFunc} />
    </div>
}
```

After rendering the component I wasn't able to enter text inside the input box. The state was not being updated for the hook I had created.

You can imagine that I have passed props to the component something like this

```
<InputField Id='user_email' label='Email' type='email' 
value={values.email} changeFunc={handleChange}/>
```

And my implementation of handleChange function

```
const handleChange = (event)=>{
        const {name,value} = event.target
        setValues((prevValues)=>{
            return {...prevValues,[name]:value}
        })
}
```

**Update**: Thank you everyone for pointing out that I had missed to add the name property to the input field.

Comment: your `input` element is missing a `name` attribute. I assume you meant `name="email"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think in `handleChange` event does not have name because you haven't set a name attribute for your input element

so i think you should just set name attribute:

```
<input
   id={props.Id}
   name="input-field-name"
   type={props.type}
   value={props.value} 
   onChange={props.changeFunc}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the name property in the input field

```
function InputField(props){
    return <div>
        <label htmlFor={props.Id}>{props.label}</label>
        <input name = {props.name} type={props.type} id={props.Id} value={props.value} 
        onChange={props.changeFunc} />
    </div>
}

<InputField Id='user_email' label='Email' type='email' 
value={values.email} changeFunc={handleChange} name="email" />
```